# Is adjective ellipsis possible when coordinating between uncountable nouns and countable nouns preceded by articles?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, articles, modifiers, ellipses, coordinating-conjunctions

A sentence like *"The man has white hair and beard"* is totally acceptable in languages without countable/uncountable nouns or articles, and languages where modifiers follow the head noun (barring gender agreement issues).

But in English, both *"The man has white [hair and _ _ beard],"* and *"The man has [white hair] and [a _ beard]"* feel inaccurate, if not ungrammatical. Only *"The man has [white hair] and [a white beard]"* feels right.

As *"He has dark [hair and _ eyes]"* seems fine, it appears the presence of the article preceding the countable noun prevents it from being modified by the overt *'white'*.

I'm looking for more information on **conjunction reduction between constituents that require an article and ones that don't, specifically in cases where adjectives are involved in the reduction.** Is this a phenomenon in English? Is there a better way to describe it, or somewhere I could read more about this specific topic?

Comment: Despite the fact that it bothers you, native English speakers seem to say *white hair and beard* more often than *white hair and a white beard*. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+hair+and+beard%2C+hair+and+a+white+beard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). I'd say dropping the article is acceptable in this case.

Comment: *"The man has [white hair] and [a _ beard]" feel[s] inaccurate, if not ungrammatical.* I don't know what dialect you speak, but to me (AmE) it sounds fine with various adjectives in that blank ("black", "long", etc.).

Comment: Interesting. I find 'the man with white hair and beard' less jarring than 'the man has white hair and beard'. I don't know why; perhaps exposure to similar strings.

Comment: This sounds way off to me (American English): *The man has white hair and beard.* Except if it were something written shorthand in a police report, and then it would later need lawyers to sort it out.

Comment: "has white hair and a beard" seems perfectly natural, but it doesn't mean that the beard is white. It's equivalent to "has a beard and white hair"